# Calculating azimuth angle for two given points using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, azimuth

We are trying to find azimuth angle through javascript for two given points
Below snapshot shows concept of azimuth angle.
[image]

We have been exploring the internet for this but no luck.
Found this link which uses postGis:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111894/how-to-calculate-the-azimuth-between-two-points-in-postgis

Comment: please share your code and show what have you tried

Comment: Try this library, use the bearing function first, then bearingToAzimuth. https://turfjs.org/docs/#bearing